# how do we get out of non-achdus and golus?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some practical things we can do to bring Moshiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16729/what-are-some-practical-things-we-can-do-to-bring-moshiach)

Given that we are still in galus (physical as well as spiritual exile), and given that our sages tell us the destruction of the second Beis Hamikdash (which caused our galus) was caused by sinas chinam (causeless hatred), how do we rectify the situation?

The simple answer of "ahavas chinam" (causeless love) isn't specific enough for me to take practical steps in ahavas yisrael (especially given the rash of negative news regarding Jews in the news media).

Comment: This would be a more valuable question asked *on* the *g'mara* that says it was *sin'as chinam* that did us in and asked for practical ways that that could have been avoided several thousand years ago. Another question could ask whether the same rules that applied to the destruction of the *Bayis* apply to it's non-rebuilding and therefore to us today.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I don't know if it can, as it was closed by a mod.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - it needs only one more vote to reopen

Comment: Try... But I am almost sure that it can't be done.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, looks like it was indeed possible. Now, if only it were that easy to answer the question...

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Never give up hope.  See what we have achieved?

Answer (score 7):

In [ליקוטי מוהר"ן א:רפב](http://www.azamra.org/sing.shtml) Rebbe Nachman zy'a outlines an essential method of engaging in baseless love for one's fellow and one's self.  In short, one must judge all people, including oneself, only on the side of merit, looking only at their good points and not at all at their faults.

If one remembers that every single individual has at least some good in them and focuses only on that, it becomes possible to love even a complete sinner.  It is necessary to not only focus on the good but to disregard the bad as irrelevant.  This world is a world of falseness and physicality and the bad has no real substance.  In the real world, the world above, only the good is lasting and permanent.

Comment: +1 Am I the only one who has Yosef Karduner's "Da" playing in the back of their head?

Comment: Do complete sinners even exist nowadays?

Comment: @AdamMosheh there's only One who can really answer that question... but I guess it depends too on your definition.

Comment: @yoel - But I cannot logically understand how somebody could ever be a rasha gamur.  Because unless he knew all of torah in its entirety, he would not be able to violate every single detail of halakhah.  But then - if he did know all of torah in its entirety, then he would know that hashkafically he would not be able to transgress.  Unless he disconnected halakhah from hashkafah, but is that even possible?

Comment: @AdamMosheh I hear you but there are different opinions - look at the first chapter of Tanya, for example.  As for whether or not a person could really be a rasha gamur, it seems to me that it is only a theoretical state and not possible in practice.  As Rebbe Nachman says, even one who would otherwise be a rasha gamur at least has the merit of being a Jew.