# Ohr HaChaim on Redemption because of Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, moshe-rabbeinu, commentaries

I've heard that the Ohr HaChaim quotes the Zohar Chadash that we will be redeemed because of the merit of Mosheh and learning Torah.

Does such a comment exist in the Ohr HaChaim? If so, can someone please source it?

(I am actually certain that I read it in the Ohr HaChaim, but I couldn't find it.)

Comment: I've heard this from HaRav Mansour Shelit"a if I remember correctly.http://www.learntorah.com/lt-shiur-details.aspx?id=5635

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in his commentary to [Ex. 27:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=454):

> מאמר הובא בס' זוהר חדש כי ד' גליות של ישראל כל א' מהם נגאלו ממנו בזכות אחד... והד' תלוי בזכות משה, ולזה נתארך הגלות, כי כל עוד שאין עוסקים בתורה ובמצות אין משה חפץ לגאול עם בטלנים מן התורה
>
> ...a statement in Zohar Chadash, that the Jews were redeemed from each of their four exiles in the merit of another person... The fourth depends on the merit of Moshe; this is why the exile is so long, for as long as we aren't occupied with Torah and mitzvos, Moshe doesn't want to redeem a people who are neglectful of Torah.

He also mentions this more briefly in his commentary to [Deut. 30:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=377):

> שבזכות עסק התורה יהיו ישראל נגאלין
>
> ...that in the merit of being occupied with Torah study, the Jews will be redeemed.