# Will the mesiah build the 3rd temple?

Tags: number, beis-hamikdash

[Some sites](http://www.jewsnews.co.il/2014/01/26/7-reasons-why-have-jews-rejected-jesus-for-over-2000-years-a-must-read-for-every-jew/) claim that the messiah will build the 3rd temple. [Another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Temple) says that the next temple, will, obviously be the 3rd.

However, Ezekiel simply envision an eternal temple. He never said it'll be the 3rd. Ezekiel lived during second temple era. Did he foresee that the 2nd won't make it till the end of time?

Why 3rd?

As opposed to the 4th, 5th, 6th, 100th? How do we know? Anything on tanach telling that?

Comment: There are also eleven sephirot and thirteen tribes. The numbering has another, non-literal significance, as always.

Comment: The Men of the Great Assembly knew the 2nd Temple wouldn't last. The Midrash derives this from a verse in Nehemia, (third paragraph):http://www.tsel.org/torah/midrashraba/pikudei.html

Comment: A source for your claim that "Ezekiel lived during second temple era" would be valuable. I've never heard of such a view, though maybe that's just me.

Comment: Not sure why you say that Ezekiel lived during the 2nd temple period, since the latest date given in the text (Ezekiel 29:17) is the 27th year of Yehoiachin's exile, c.571 BCE. That's over half a century before the second temple was even built.

Comment: As mentioned [in a comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36991/will-the-mesiah-build-the-3rd-temple#comment96927_36995), "[The title asks one question, but t]he question text asks two other questions: why ezekiel prophesied about an eternal temple before the second, and why we believe the third will be the last."

Comment: Oh ezekiel live during first temple era. Hmmm... I was wrong then.

Comment: Where do people get the idea that the last temple will be the third one? In fact, the fact that ezekiel told this during first temple era would make it even more impressive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rashi ([Sukkah 41a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=41&format=pdf) "I nami") says that the third temple will come down built from heaven.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The asker asked how we know the third temple will be the final one, as opposed to being one of many; and whether Ezekiel knew the second would be followed by another, or thought his vision of an eternal temple referred to the second.

Comment: @msh210 this answer answers the question in the title. The question text asks two other questions: why ezekiel prophesied about an eternal temple before the second, and why we believe the third will be the last. Perhaps Jim should be consulted as to what exactly he wants to know, and advised to edit is question title, or the text, and make new questions for his other quandaries.

Comment: @BabySeal, I took the title to mean "Is the temple that the messiah will build [=that will be built in his day by whomever] the third, or is it possibly a fourth or fifth?". I agree the question could be much better worded.

Comment: Actually, @BabySeal, this answer doesn't answer the question in the title either. The OP asked whether or not the messiah will build the 3rd temple, not whether or not Rashi thought that he would do so. Is Rashi's opinion the only one? Does nobody disagree with him about this? Was he mentioning something that everybody already believed? If so, why did he bother to say it? This answer gives one person's opinion on the topic only, and therefore isn't actually an answer.

Comment: @shimonbm wasn't aware that mi yodeya answers now had to be comprehensive theses.

Comment: There's no point being sarcastic, @BabySeal - I don't think they need to be comprehensive theses either. There is, however, a huge difference between a "comprehensive thesis" and a single line, conveying what a single individual once said. This answer could be vastly improved without even coming close to being a "thesis".

Comment: @ShimonbM Generally speaking, answers bring down and idea or two that addresses the question. This does. With brevity perhaps, but what more is there to be said? The temple will comedown from heaven, acc. To Rashi, thus, accto Rashi, no,the messiah will not build the third temple. Sorry for the sarcasm, I realized after I commented that it was rude of me.

Comment: @ShimonbM rashi is giving the plain meaning of the talmud not his own personal opinion. see there.