# Is asking questions on Mi Yodeya considered learning "Torah l'shma?"

Tags: torah-study, stackexchange

Due to the mechanics of Stack Overflow- upvoting, accepting answers, getting medals, unlocking privileges- there are many factors that encourage and reward active participation on Stack Overflow and its network of sites.

Since our site is part of this network and contains all of these elements, can we say that asking questions on Mi Yodeya is **truly** *Torah l'shma*?

Comment: similar to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9445

Comment: When was such a claim presented

Comment: Important premise: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33723/what-is-learning-torah-lishma

Comment: Even if one only engages in MY.SE for virtual rewards or “internet cred” such learning is [still worthwhile](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.23b.5?with=all&lang=bi).