# Does participating in Mi Yodeya count as an "addictive hobby", which would therefore forbid us from using it according to Rav Moshe Feinstein Y'D 3:35

Tags: halacha-theory, social-media

Rav Moshe is very strict about this.

Stack Exchange has a points system, equivalent to "likes" on other platforms. This system has been demonstrated to be highly addictive as we get a dopamine rush every time we get a like<sup>1</sup>

So, would Rav Moshe be opposed to us participating in Mi Yodeya? Is there any mitigation because it is a cause of increased Torah learning?

---

<sup>1 eg Lindström, B., Bellander, M., Chang, A., Tobler, P.N., & Amodio, D.M. (2019). A computational reinforcement learning account of social media engagement. PsyArXiv, for one such study out of many</sup>

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote but don't want to exacerbate the problem.

Comment: But on a serious note, the question makes no sense to me. The problem with addiction is that it takes you away from important things we're supposed to be doing. If you're addicted to learning, how is that a bad thing? Unless you conisder this not learning but a waste of time, in which case the addictiveness is beside the point.

Comment: I propose a middle case. It's not a waste of time but it's not the best use of one's learning time, and is only considered appropriate in small amounts. Therefore, the addictiveness might cause a person to engage with it more than is healthy or appropriate.

Comment: [*P'sachim* 50b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.50b?lang=bi): "אָמַר רַב יְהוּדָה אָמַר רַב לְעוֹלָם יַעֲסוֹק אָדָם בְּתוֹרָה וּמִצְוֹת אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁלֹּא לִשְׁמָהּ שֶׁמִּתּוֹךְ שֶׁלֹּא לִשְׁמָהּ בָּא לִשְׁמָהּ".

Comment: @shmosel any addiction is bad, even learning. You may be ignoring other things you may need to do, such as taking care of your family, or maybe even eating.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98995/is-asking-questions-on-mi-yodeya-considered-learning-torah-lshma

Comment: And this: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9445/does-reputation-scoring-make-the-torah-a-crown-to-magnify-yourself-with

Comment: Thanks everyone for not upvoting the question:) Rav Moshe can be read that it's forbidden to _start a new_ addictive hobby, so we are ok

Comment: Just so people know -- Rabbi Feinstein was talking about recreational marijuana use there.

Comment: @Shalom Even if you can argue that he was limiting it to only that, many of the studies have likened the level of addiction social media causes to cocaine or heroine, so I suggest kal vchomer

Comment: Is studying Torah an "addictive hobby"?  Isn't that what we are doing here?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I'd say this might be more similar to a system where people are offered recreational drugs in reward for writing good divrei Torah or asking good sheilot