# Moshiach or gan eden

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, chabad

What is the purpose of everything, our Torah and mitzvos.

Is it to go to gan Eden in olam haba or is it to bring moshiach?

Whenever I ask people usually I get either answer.
Can someone clarify like why do I never hear Chabad Rabbis saying "do a mitzvah to go to gan Eden"
But rather they say to bring moshiach. 
Are they missing something?

The same is with litvaks - they barely speak of doing things to bring moshiach.

Comment: Why are those the only two options?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28682/759

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60545/759

Comment: I wrote that people tell me

Comment: They are ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: @ close voters, [the preexisting question](/q/60545) asks "We know that hashem created the whole world only for the purpose of human's on earth. Everything else is there for his benefit to obtain his purpose. So the question is, what real purpose does he have. And do all human beings have the same purpose." i.e. what is **my** (or P'loni's) purpose for existing. This one asks "What is the purpose of everything, our Torah and mitzvos." i.e. what is the Torah and mitzvos' purpose for existing. These seem like two different questions.

Comment: Thank you for speaking up this happened so many times on this website they don't even read it they just please don't forget and it keeps running and your gation maybe

Answer (score 4):

In the Path of the Just [ch.1](http://dafyomireview.com/mesilat.php?d=3&e=0) Rabbi Moshe Chaim [Luzzato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Luzzatto) says:

> Behold, our sages, of blessed memory, have taught us that man was
>   created solely to rejoice in G-d and to delight in the splendor of the
>   Shechina (divine presence). For this is true joy, and the greatest
>   possible pleasure that can possibly exist. The place of this joy is,
>   in truth, in Olam Haba (the afterlife). For it was created expressly
>   for this purpose... The means which lead a person to this goal are the
>   commandments which the blessed G-d commanded to us... Therefore, man
>   was first placed in this world so that through these means prepared
>   for him here, he will be able to reach the place prepared for him,
>   namely, the afterlife, there to be sated with the good which he
>   acquired through these means. This is what our sages of blessed memory
>   said "today to do them, and tomorrow to receive their reward" (Eruvin
>   22:1)

No mention of Moshiach here. Just do what you're supposed to do and the rest will come when God deems fit.