# What did the lubvitcher rebbe mean?

Tags: messiah, how-to, chabad, quotations

On chof cheis Nissan 5751 the Chabad Rebbe said in a public address "I did all I can to bring moshiach now I leave it up to you"

What does this mean that he did everything he could? What do we still need to do? What should we do to bring moshiach?

I know we can't take any word a tzadik says lightly especially since the Chabad Rebbe is know as the nasi hador by many gedolim.

Comment: Why don't you read the Sicha (and the upcoming ones)??

Comment: Here's a good book of things to do to bring Mashiach http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&pgnum=1

Comment: What is a "nasi hador"? I don't remember encountering such a term anywhere in my Torah studies.

Comment: "I know we can't take any word a tzadik says lightly" source?

Comment: Tzadikim domem leborom  just like hashem is perfect so too are his tzadikim  daled ois Hummel in Rus Rabba

Comment: Actually double aa's comment here is right. Here is a story that illustrates this point...https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/pc5772unwrapit/F-Z2V96FMHI

Comment: @menachem Tzaddikim aren't perfect. Moshe sinned, for instance, and couldn't enter Israel. Only 4 people are recorded in the Midrash as not having sinner. Surely there have been more than 4 Tzaddikim in history!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to quote from Rut Rabbah. I was unable to find it in Rut Rabba. I dont understand your comment "previous to you". I have never seen any source in Judaism that states that any human beings are perfect. This seems like a very strange and foreign idea. Although one can find a source for anything I think mainstream sources are clear that this is not the case. Is not Masekhet Horayot predicated on the existence of human fallibility? As@DoubleAA noted the fallibility extends to Moshe Rabbenu; arguably the greatest Jew of all time.

Comment: This is *possibly* a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16729

Comment: @mevaqesh source ועליה לא יבול אפילו שיחת חולין של תלמידי חכמים צריכה לימודא if I remember good it is in 3st chapter of massechet succa.

Comment: @kouty That is very different from any sort of Catholic infallibility! It just says that the opinion of an expert in a field ought to be valued. A _talmid chacham_ who is an expert in the realm of Torah should be reckoned with accordingly, and his words should be weighed to determine if they contain Torah insight. Notably, that passage speaks not of _tzadikkim_, but of _talmidei chachamim_.

Comment: @menachem please try to give your questions meaningful titles.  People should not have to read the question to get some idea of what the question is about.  Thank you.

Comment: @mevaqesh, Chumash with Rashi - I recommend it. http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9949/jewish/Chapter-21.htm#showrashi=true&v=21

Comment: How many non-Chabad "gedolim" can you identify who referred to RMMS as "nasi hador"?

Comment: @Yishai Indeed some quick research suggests that that singular usage in Rashi is the earliest source for this expression. It is noteworthy that it is mentioned a total of 18 times in the entire Bar-Ilan database, a few of which are commentators on Rashi. This tells us that it is an obscure expression of little importance in broad Jewish thought. There is no reason to think that it is anything more than a mere expression; i.e. that there is a "din nasi hador". If the term has been co-opted to mean something specific or technical, it should be edited into the question.

Comment: @Dude this should probably be submitted as an answer on its own, as there is no one to better answer the question then the Rebbe himself.

Comment: The shabbos after chof ches Nissan the Rebbe discussed what to do. Look it up.

Comment: I don't think anyone non-chabad has heard of 'nasi hador' or considered him as such when he was alive (.... kal vechomer now that he's not alive).

Comment: Purely for interest's sake: I think the Alter Rebbe held that an act of tzedakah would bring Moshiach. (Anyone have the source for this; is it Tanya?)

Answer (score 2):

By doing those specific things the rebbe told us will bring moshiach

1) “They should add in learning Torah 
– nigleh and chassidus, 
2) fulfilling mitzvos b'hidur, 
3) adding in ahavas Yisroel and 
4) the spreading of chassidus.”

Specifically adding in learning should include inyanim in geula and about moshiach

http://www.lmaanyishmeu.com/pdf/108%20-%20Bringing%20Moshiach.pdf look under hastening his coming

Comment: But what does it mean he did everything he could

Comment: Look at basi legani. This was a maamar written by the previous rebbe but he didnt say it. The rebbe said this as his first maamar when he finally accepted the role of being rebbe and outlined how his responsibility is to bring moshiach. Since it didnt happen it now has to be up to us

Comment: But he said its up to us before gimmel Tammuz

Comment: He was suposed to tell us after gimmel tamuz how? A tzadik knows the time of his passing. The year prior to accepting leadership and the final years were targeted to preparing us for when the rebbe wouldnt be here physically

Comment: I just don't understand how the middle of his lifetime he could say he did everything he could

Comment: It wasnt the middle of his lifetime it was in 1991 and the rebbes histalkus was in 1994

Answer (score 0):

The Rebbe meant that mashiach is a transition between a spiritually collapsing universe and a spiritually expanding universe.

The closer we align our actions to the state of the world after mashiach arrives, the less of a change there has to be in the current world order for mashiach to arrive.

Therefore mashiach needs you as much as you need mashiach.

Comment: How do you know this is what he meant?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that the magnitude of the change between the current world and the world of Mashiach is an impediment to his arrival? Why is it an impediment? Will God have trouble adjusting things if they are too different but the people are deserving?