# What can Noahides do to help bring the Moshiach?

Tags: noachide-laws, messianic-redemption

I'm curious if there is anything Noahides (including myself) can do to help the coming of the Moshiach? I was told that being "righteous" will help in the messianic process but I am left wondering what "being righteous" means exactly. I know that being good to others and treating others with respect will certainly help but is there a technique or a way of doing things that would be good for Noahides to follow? I am open to any suggestions as well as what books to purchase/read that would help me along the way. Thank you

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16729/759

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure if that question is referring to Jews or Noahides....the text says "average person" but I am not sure what he is referring to.

Comment: One way you could help in the coming of the Moshiach is helping other non-Jews observe the Seven Noahide Laws, and especially in belief in the one true G-d.

Comment: @ezra Is there a source for that?

Comment: "I know that being good to others and treating others with respect will certainly help" - what makes you think so?